# EWS MeetingTimeZone TimeZoneName consisting of only &#x0; characters

Tags: xml, soap, exchange-server, office365, exchangewebservices

We have a customer where several `GetItem` SOAP calls to Exchange Web Services return XML containing:

```
<t:MeetingTimeZone TimeZoneName="&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;">
```

(32 null characters). Subsequently, my XML.XmlDoc.LoadXMLData call raises an 'Invalid Unicode-character' EDOMParseError on that line - *of course*.

The server version is:

```
<h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="361" MinorBuildNumber="14" Version="V2015_10_05" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

This is the online Exchange365.

**What can be going on here? How can this weird TimeZoneName creep in? Can it be prevented?**

The only thing I can recommend now is that they recreate these appointments and check if the issue goes away, *or* filter the `&#x0;` out of the XML which will reduce speed.

FWIW, here is the full XML returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="361" MinorBuildNumber="14" Version="V2015_10_05" />
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <m:GetItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
          <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
          <m:Items>
            <t:CalendarItem>
              <t:ItemId Id="AQMkAG[snip]AAAA==" ChangeKey="DwAA[snip]pg28O" />
              <t:ParentFolderId Id="AQMk[snip]AAAA==" ChangeKey="AQAAAA==" />
              <t:ItemClass>IPM.Appointment</t:ItemClass>
              <t:Subject>Daily Scrum</t:Subject>
              <t:Sensitivity>Normal</t:Sensitivity>
              <t:Body BodyType="Text">Something</t:Body>
              <t:DateTimeReceived>2014-04-16T06:18:23Z</t:DateTimeReceived>
              <t:Size>7972</t:Size>
              <t:Importance>Normal</t:Importance>
              <t:IsSubmitted>false</t:IsSubmitted>
              <t:IsDraft>false</t:IsDraft>
              <t:IsFromMe>false</t:IsFromMe>
              <t:IsResend>false</t:IsResend>
              <t:IsUnmodified>false</t:IsUnmodified>
              <t:DateTimeSent>2014-04-16T06:18:23Z</t:DateTimeSent>
              <t:DateTimeCreated>2014-04-16T06:17:40Z</t:DateTimeCreated>
              <t:ResponseObjects>
                <t:ForwardItem />
              </t:ResponseObjects>
              <t:ReminderDueBy>2015-12-21T08:15:00Z</t:ReminderDueBy>
              <t:ReminderIsSet>true</t:ReminderIsSet>
              <t:ReminderMinutesBeforeStart>0</t:ReminderMinutesBeforeStart>
              <t:DisplayCc />
              <t:DisplayTo />
              <t:HasAttachments>false</t:HasAttachments>
              <t:Culture>nl-NL</t:Culture>
              <t:EffectiveRights>
                <t:CreateAssociated>false</t:CreateAssociated>
                <t:CreateContents>false</t:CreateContents>
                <t:CreateHierarchy>false</t:CreateHierarchy>
                <t:Delete>true</t:Delete>
                <t:Modify>true</t:Modify>
                <t:Read>true</t:Read>
              </t:EffectiveRights>
              <t:LastModifiedName>Mark de Waal</t:LastModifiedName>
              <t:LastModifiedTime>2015-12-17T09:14:40Z</t:LastModifiedTime>
              <t:UID>04000[snip]1A2FD6</t:UID>
              <t:DateTimeStamp>2015-12-17T09:14:40Z</t:DateTimeStamp>
              <t:Start>2015-06-10T07:15:00Z</t:Start>
              <t:End>2015-06-10T07:30:00Z</t:End>
              <t:IsAllDayEvent>false</t:IsAllDayEvent>
              <t:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>Busy</t:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>
              <t:IsMeeting>false</t:IsMeeting>
              <t:IsCancelled>false</t:IsCancelled>
              <t:IsRecurring>false</t:IsRecurring>
              <t:MeetingRequestWasSent>false</t:MeetingRequestWasSent>
              <t:IsResponseRequested>true</t:IsResponseRequested>
              <t:CalendarItemType>RecurringMaster</t:CalendarItemType>
              <t:MyResponseType>Unknown</t:MyResponseType>
              <t:Organizer>
                <t:Mailbox>
                  <t:Name>Mark de Waal</t:Name>
                  <t:EmailAddress>m[snip].com</t:EmailAddress>
                  <t:RoutingType>SMTP</t:RoutingType>
                </t:Mailbox>
              </t:Organizer>
              <t:Duration>PT15M</t:Duration>
              <t:TimeZone />
              <t:AppointmentSequenceNumber>0</t:AppointmentSequenceNumber>
              <t:AppointmentState>0</t:AppointmentState>
              <t:Recurrence>
                <t:WeeklyRecurrence>
                  <t:Interval>1</t:Interval>
                  <t:DaysOfWeek>Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday</t:DaysOfWeek>
                </t:WeeklyRecurrence>
                <t:NoEndRecurrence>
                  <t:StartDate>2015-06-10+02:00</t:StartDate>
                </t:NoEndRecurrence>
              </t:Recurrence>
              <t:FirstOccurrence>
                <t:ItemId Id="AAMk[snip]AEA==" ChangeKey="DwAA[snip]pg28O" />
                <t:Start>2015-06-10T07:15:00Z</t:Start>
                <t:End>2015-06-10T07:30:00Z</t:End>
                <t:OriginalStart>2015-06-10T07:15:00Z</t:OriginalStart>
              </t:FirstOccurrence>
              <t:MeetingTimeZone TimeZoneName="&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;">
                <t:BaseOffset>-PT60M</t:BaseOffset>
                <t:Standard TimeZoneName="Standard">
                  <t:Offset>PT0M</t:Offset>
                  <t:RelativeYearlyRecurrence>
                    <t:DaysOfWeek>Sunday</t:DaysOfWeek>
                    <t:DayOfWeekIndex>Last</t:DayOfWeekIndex>
                    <t:Month>October</t:Month>
                  </t:RelativeYearlyRecurrence>
                  <t:Time>02:00:00</t:Time>
                </t:Standard>
                <t:Daylight TimeZoneName="Daylight">
                  <t:Offset>-PT60M</t:Offset>
                  <t:RelativeYearlyRecurrence>
                    <t:DaysOfWeek>Sunday</t:DaysOfWeek>
                    <t:DayOfWeekIndex>Last</t:DayOfWeekIndex>
                    <t:Month>March</t:Month>
                  </t:RelativeYearlyRecurrence>
                  <t:Time>03:00:00</t:Time>
                </t:Daylight>
              </t:MeetingTimeZone>
              <t:ConferenceType>0</t:ConferenceType>
              <t:IsOnlineMeeting>false</t:IsOnlineMeeting>
              <t:NetShowUrl />
            </t:CalendarItem>
          </m:Items>
        </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:GetItemResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the online exchange. Please submit it here:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues

(Microsoft tracks graph api issues in GitHub. When you report any issue to the graph api they fix it and publish it to the graph api documentation that you see on the web. All o365 services including EWS is part of graph api for o365).

Comment: I believe this answer is incorrect. [The Graph API is a REST interface](http://graph.microsoft.io/docs), the EWS SOAP interface has no connection with it.